# SyntaxError: Can't create duplicate variable: 'userProf' в консоли

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS и столкнулся с таким моментом - в консоли когда вбиваешь данный код, выдает ошибку

> SyntaxError: Can't create duplicate variable: 'userProf'

А результат функции не получает, почему такая ошибка

```
const userProf = {
    name: 'Eugen',
    ageQty: 17,
    hasArgument: false,
  };
  
  const userInform = ({ name, ageQty }) => {
    if (!ageQty) {
      return `User ${name} has no comment`;
    }
    return `User ${name} has ${ageQty} comment`;
  };
  
  userInform(userProf);
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы уже объявили эту переменную. Либо она где-то встречается на сайте

Comment: Спасибо! Буду смотреть :))